# Sampling from earths landmass

Tags: python, dataset, geospatial

Given a sphere which resembles earth, I want to sample points where land would be. I am struggling to find a dataset to sample from, and even to find a dataset which I could use to generate a set of such points.

Does anybody an according dataset / a nice workaround?

Comment: Could you please clarify the "land"? What is your objective? A simple solution could be to draw a 3D sphere with a 3D tool like Blender, and export the data as mesh coordinates.

Comment: @NicolasMartin My objective is to get a dataset consisting of euclidian coordinates of points on the sphere, where the coordinate systems origin aligns with the one of the sphere. Each coordiante in the dataset correpsonds to a point on earth which is not covered by water, but by land.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47894513/checking-if-a-geocoordinate-point-is-land-or-ocean-with-cartopy

Comment: Yes, it does. Thank you! If you want you can create an answer and I will mark it as solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [cartopy](https://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/latest/installing.html) to achieve this easily.

> pip install cartopy

For instance:

```
import cartopy.io.shapereader as shpreader
import shapely.geometry as sgeom
from shapely.ops import unary_union
from shapely.prepared import prep

land_shp_fname = shpreader.natural_earth(resolution='50m',
                                       category='physical', name='land')

land_geom = unary_union(list(shpreader.Reader(land_shp_fname).geometries()))
land = prep(land_geom)

def is_land(x, y):
    return land.contains(sgeom.Point(x, y))

>>> print(is_land(0, 0))
False
>>> print(is_land(0, 10))
True
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47894513/checking-if-a-geocoordinate-point-is-land-or-ocean-with-cartopy